# Can I specify the same Firebase rule for several key/value pairs in the same path?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Say I have these Firebase paths:

```
/project/name
/project/order
/project/approver
```

I want the same rules to apply for `/name` and `/order`, but a different url for `/approver`. I know I can make the rules e.g. pseudo rules:

```
{ "name": { ".read": "anyone" } }
{ "order": { ".read": "anyone" } }
{ "approver": { ".read": "admin" } }
```

but what I'd really like is

```
{ "name", "order": { ".read": "anyone" } }
{ "approver": { ".read": "admin" } }
```

the reason being that's is a fairly complex rule (6 different boolean checks), and I have a lot of similar rule needs across the project.

Is there a rule syntax that will work for me? (not a rules compiler)